# Saving the state of an oracle database to revert back to?

Tags: java, oracle, persistence, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am creating with a `Java` application that uses has `persistable data`.

I am testing it with an `Oracle Database`, using `SQLDeveloper`.

Currently, in order to populate the database with test data I do so by using my application. 
When I stop running my application the data is *removed* from the DB.

Is there a way that I can save the state of the database so that I can *revert* to it than populating it through my application?

Comment: Take a [snapshot](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/server.816/a76959/mview.htm). Also, don't forget to `commit` your *writes*.

Comment: Do you want the state of the entire database, or of a schema, or of specific tables? How long do you need to save it for, and do you need to go back to the same starting point often (and over a long period of time)? There are various options - truncate/insert scripts, export/import, flashback database, full backup and restore... depends what you actually need to do, and what your DBA will be happy with.

Comment: Commit it. That way it will persist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you need it while testing, not in production.
Oracle Database provides a technology called [Flashback](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_flashback.htm). It allows setting back the database to a certain time in the past. If it is available in your license variant, you may want to give it a try.

Comment: You can flashback at the database and at the table level; both would require appropriate (usually DBA) authority.